How should I repair this wall and siding damage from old conduit?
An electrician came and upgraded our service a few months ago. You can see the new meter and thick service conduits in the photo.
However, they left holes where the previous conduit was, as shown in the two red arrows in the photo.
What should I do to repair this damage?
(Ignore the old cables and Ameritech box shown in the photo.)


I'm unhappy about the gratuitous damage caused by the new installation, particularly if the existing meter had already been removed or it was the electrician's job to both remove the old meter and fit the new one.

For the sill cut a piece of wood to fit the void. Apply plenty of caulk before inserting the new piece.  When dry paint.
For the concrete opening apply stucco repair patch. Prime and paint when dry.

I'd be tempted to treat that like a car body repair: fill the void, apply plastic padding over expanded metal, sand flat and spray.

@RMDman not replace the aluminum flashing?

I agree with @Huesmann. The flashing should be replaced because it was there to prevent water infiltration. The cutout for the new conduit should have been covered, as well, because the exposed wood will be damaged in a short time.

@Huesmann,  If that is flashing, sure replace or recover it.  My old eyes saw what I thought was just a wood piece with a square cut out.  Definitely shows how analysing a repair is more difficult from a pic rather than being there.  Most of the time we never know the entirety of the situation.

explaining from a photo how to fix anything is most difficult.....if you were there you would probably fix it completely different from how you explained to someone to fix it.......does that make sense
